# Virtualbox failing to create IP addresses for imported VMs

Tags: networking, virtualbox, 18.04, virtualization

I'm trying to learn more penetration testing skills by testing myself against a prebuilt vulnerable server. However, when it comes time to connect to the guest server through the host OS (ubuntu 18.04), the IP address is not generated - as the VM's instructions say. When I request the IP address straight after installing, it says there is no IP address set. I've tried manually setting the IP address for the server with no luck.

The virtual machine is an Ubuntu server with two network adapters - one NAT and the other bridged to the host only adapter. I have no port forwarding instructions on the NAT device.

Is there something I'm missing? What could be causing this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a NAT Network defined in File>Preferences>Network to assign IP addresses in VirtualBox?

Comment: @Terrance yes, it also has DHCP enabled. One thing that I noticed is that the NAT network and the Host network IPs are on different networks (NAT starting at 10, Host starting at 192). Do they both have to be on the same network to properly function?

Comment: Not with NAT.  Only Bridged.  With NAT they should be in different networks so there is no confusion for the packet forwarding to the right location.  So, in the guest OS if set to DHCP, they should be getting a 10.x.x.x IP address then.